# Webpack error adding storybook to create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, storybook

Today I created a new CRA project (working perfectly) but when I add Storybook with `npx sb init` I get this error:

```html
info @storybook/react v6.4.9

info => Loading presets
info => Serving static files from ./public at /
info => Loading Webpack configuration from `node_modules/react-scripts`
info => Removing existing JavaScript and TypeScript rules.
info => Modifying Create React App rules.
info => Using default Webpack5 setup
ERR! ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
ERR!  - configuration.module.rules[4] should be one of these:
ERR!    ["..." | object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
```

I tried a lot of things with no results.

What could it be?

Thank you!

Comment: it looks you have configuration issue in webpack config. and this is pointing to rule number 4.

Comment: Is this normal in a default installation?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? How? I have the exact same issue with latest CRA/storybook, CRA not ejected thus webpack config hidden in node_modules and not customised. It seems SB is changing the webpack config (in-memory?) before using it for its build, and the resulting config is incorrect.
As a workaround, I've downgraded to CRA 4 and re-initialised storybook, but I'd love to be on the latest CRA/SB :)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this. Using storybook with Create React App v5 which uses webpack5 ?

Answer (score 3):

Storybook 6.3 brings opt-in support for building both your project and the manager UI with webpack 5. To do so:

```
yarn add @storybook/builder-webpack5 @storybook/manager-webpack5 --dev

# or

npm install @storybook/builder-webpack5 @storybook/manager-webpack5 --save-dev
```

Then edit your .storybook/main.js config:

```
module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
};
```

Comment: Just ran into the same problem, despite having these dependencies and config.

Answer (score -1):

> Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

Please review your webpack configuration: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack

Comment: But I have the default create-react-app and the default installation of storybook. Is this a bug?

Comment: It should work, but please review the webpack configuration, the error is clear. This can happen for dozens of reasons so it's better to follow the instructions in the link I shared and making sure webpack is configured correctly.